# How do I define Junit Test Case without using @Test annotation

Tags: java, junit

I need to do Junit Test Case without using `@Test` annotation. It is working fine if I use `@Test` annotation.

I would like to go for automation testing to perform Junit Testing as a bulk. Can you please give me some sample program to do that ?

**Note:** I have tried Test Suite so please don't give any examples regarding the Test Suite.

Comment: Using @Test is 'a' correct way. why would want it otherway?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This looks like an XY problem.

Comment: It would help us if you showed us the code you tried, and the errors that you got. You also (as mentioned above) probably need to explain why you need it to be done this other way.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. Now we are following junit test case using @Test annotation. Thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `JUnit 3`

```
import junit.framework.TestCase; 

public class DummyTestA extends TestCase {
    public void testSum() {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 10;
        int result = a + b;
        assertEquals(15, result);
    } 
}
```

But generally you should choose the annotation path, unless compatibility with `JUnit 3` (and/or a Java version earlier than Java 5) is needed for several reasons:

- The `@Test` annotation is more explicit and is easier to support in
  tools (for example it's easy to search for all tests this way)
- Multiple methods can be annotated with `@Before/@BeforeClass` and
  `@After/@AfterClass` providing more flexibility
- Integrated support for testing for expected exceptions using
  `expected=`
- Integrated support of the `@Ignored annotation`
- new features of `JUnit 4`: [rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules), [parametrized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests), ...

see also [JUnit website](http://junit.org)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try and update here about the issue/result.

Comment: @RC thnx for the edit... It looks better now.

Comment: @PradeepJ My suggestion to you is to use annotations unless compatibility with JUnit 3 (and/or a Java version earlier than Java 5).